# Efficient way to iterate through a DataSnapshot's children

Tags: android, firebase, garbage-collection, firebase-realtime-database

Which of these two code fragments is more efficient or are they both the same?

assume the database is like this:

```
root
- userUID
-- messageUID
---- text:""
---- sentTo:""
-- messageUID2 {...}
-- messageUID3 {...}
-- messageUID4 {...}
```

then the first thing I tried was this

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      //..
      ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
      for(DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Message message = messageSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
        messageList.add(message);
      }
      //..
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){
      //..
    }

});
```

but then I noticed I would be creating a lot of Message objects. Would this be more efficient?

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
      //..
      ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        Message message = new Message("","");
        for(DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
          message.setText(messageSnapshot.getValue("text");
          message.setSentTo(messageSnapshot.getValue("sentTo");
          messageList.add(message);
        }
      //..
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){
      //..
    }

});
```

Comment: This seems like premature, micro-optimization to me. Most modern VMs will optimize the `Message` in that tight loop anyway.